# Left join query is executing very slow for large data in tables

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, query-optimization

following is my query ,that i am executing in navicat my sql on tables which contains more than 91000 records.

```
select l.* 
from localcdrsmem l 
LEFT JOIN (
         SELECT LocalCDRID, ForeignCDRsID 
         from localcdrsmem l 
         INNER JOIN foreigncdrsmem f 
         ON l.CalledNumber=f.CalledNumber and 
         ABS(l.Duration-f.Duration)<= 2 and            
         ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,f.StartTime,l.StartTime))<=100 
         group by l.CalledNumber) 
as temp ON l.LocalCDRID = temp.LocalCDRID 
where temp.LocalCDRID IS NULL;
```

tables are :

```
localcdrsmem - > 
+---------+------------+--------+----------
localcdrid | callednumber | duration | starttime
+---------+------------+--------+----------+
foreigncdrsmem- > 
+------------+------------+--------+----------
foreigncdrid | callednumber | duration | starttime
+---------+------------+--------+----------+
```

Any ideas for optimization of this query??

Comment: I'm guessing it's the use of math and functions in the join clause, but can you give us the output of an `EXPLAIN`?

Comment: How much time does the inner query take compared to the whole thing?

Comment: i actualy want to get those records from first table localcdrsmem which are not present in the table left joined to it through subquery.

Comment: inner query is taking almost 1.481s to execute

Comment: Can you add the tables' definitions? Which columns are the primary keys?

Comment: Try to remove the outer query, and make the INNER JOIN a LEFT (add the IS NULL WHERE clause to the inner one). Also I'm not sure what the `group by l.CalledNumber` is suppose to do, it looks like someone tried to 'fix' something with it.

Comment: yes group by is used here to fix the query to return only one record.but issue is not with that inner query..it is taking only 1.4s to execute...there is problem with that left join might be which makes it to execute very slowly...

Comment: That's the reason you should move it to the inner query and remove the outer one.

Comment: These are not table definitions. Add the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE localcdrsmem;` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE foreigncdrsmem;`

Answer (score -1):

```
select l.* from localcdrsmem l LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT LocalCDRID, ForeignCDRsID from localcdrsmem l 
INNER JOIN foreigncdrsmem f
ON l.CalledNumber=f.CalledNumber 
WHERE ABS(l.Duration-f.Duration)<= 2 
and ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,f.StartTime,l.StartTime))<=100 
group by l.CalledNumber) as temp
ON l.LocalCDRID = temp.LocalCDRID where temp.LocalCDRID IS NULL;
```

Try this query above. This query execute faster. Just change `and` statement with `where` clause after this statement `ON l.CalledNumber=f.CalledNumber`. You can see the difference between our query.

Comment: Why would there be any difference?

Comment: the difference is only time execution